Cannot open file directory 'spdlog/spdlog.h': No such file or directory
So I'm getting this fatal error from Visual Studio 2022 and I don't really undertand why it`s happening, since I clearly included the right path to the "include" folder from spdlog in the project properties.

Here is the additional include directories of the Sandbox solution.

In the additional include directories I inserted the path to the include folder inside spdlog $(SolutionDir)vendor\\spdlog\\include. I checked a lot of times and the path seems correct.
Just showing this print so you can see that the path actually exists in my pc

Just to be clear, the $(SolutionDir) is located in the same folder as "vendor". And the weirdest thing about it is that even the VS is recognizing the functions and types from "spdlog.h". There are no explicit errors on the code either, so I don't know what happened for this error to happen after compiling.
The compiler recognizing the path to the .h file

The code with no sign of errors

This question is not really about the code itself, but Im still gonnha put my code in here for review.
The code I'm trying to run and getting the error Log.h:
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#include "Core.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"

namespace Rend {

    class REND_API Log
    {
    public:
        static void Init();

        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }

    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;

    };
}

Log.cpp:
#include "Log.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"

namespace Rend {

    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_CoreLogger;
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_ClientLogger;

    void Log::Init()
    {
        spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T] %n: %v%$");
        s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("Rend");
        s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

        s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP");
        s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

    }
}

I tried some things I could to fix the problem, like trying to change the directory of the "spdlog" folder to another, but nothing worked and I kept getting the same error over and over. I reviewed the file names a lot of times too and everything seems alright about that.
I believe the error might be from Visual Studio itself, so that's why I tagged it, but I'm not sure about it.
I would appreciate if someone knows what is happening, because I've been trying to fix this for quite a while right now and it's still happening. Thx!

Ensure that you select the proper build configuration that you setup in the project settings.

Are you sure you have read access to the directory and files in question?

In the second picture, are you sure you don't need a '/' between the variable and the string?
